# Proof by Induction with Two Basis

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, induction

I did an assignment where I used the proof by induction three times in the same manner, and now I have doubts creeping up whether this method was valid or not. I would be quite relieved if you could tell me if that's correct or not:

> The sequence $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is given through $$a_1 = 1,\quad a_2 = \frac{1}{2},\quad a_{n+2}=a_na_{n+1} \text{ for } n\geq 1.$$

I want to show $A(n): a_n \geq a_{n+1} \forall\, n\geq 1$. So I did the base case as follows $$n=1:\quad a_1 = 1,\quad a_2=\frac{1}{2},\quad \therefore a_1=1 \geq \frac{1}{2} = a_2 \quad\checkmark$$
$$n=2:\quad a_2 = \frac{1}{2},\quad a_3=\frac{1}{2},\quad \therefore a_2=\frac{1}{2} \geq \frac{1}{2} = a_3 \quad\checkmark$$
Now comes the part where I'm insecure. For the induction step I assume that $A(n): a_{n} \geq a_{n+1}$ and $A(n+1): a_{n+1} \geq a_{n+2}$ are true and I want to deduce $A(n+2): a_{n+2} \geq a_{n+3}$. Because of the ordering axiom of $(\mathbb{R},+,\cdot\,)$ I think I can multiply $A(n)$ and $A(n+1)$ to get $$a_n \cdot a_{n+1} \geq a_{n+1} \cdot a_{n+2}$$
and with the definition of the recursive defined sequence $a_n$ I would get
$$a_{n+2} = a_n \cdot a_{n+1} \quad\geq\quad a_{n+1} \cdot a_{n+2} = a_{(n+1)+2} =  a_{n+3} \quad\checkmark$$
the induction step.

### Do I get away with this?

Comment: Do you know about strong induction and/or are you allowed to use that proof technique?  Or are you just supposed to use regular induction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That works if you first prove (by induction) that all $a_n$ are positive. That will let you apply the ordering axiom as you stated.

For an example of why you need them positive,

$$5 \geq 4$$
$$-1 \geq -1$$

but it is not true that
$$-5 \geq -4$$

---

Strictly speaking, you are appealing to a slightly stronger induction principle than the one which is usually stated at school level. The weaker principle is "If $P(1)$, and if $P(n) \Rightarrow P(n+1)$, then $P(n)$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$." The stronger principle is "If $P(1)$ and $P(2)$, and $P(n), P(n+1) \Rightarrow P(n+2)$, then $P(n)$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$." Both principles are completely correct and true.

In fact, it gets more general: "If $P(1)$, and if $(\forall n < m)(P(m))$ implies $P(n)$, then $P(n)$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$." (Do you see why this includes both the one-step and the two-step induction principles as special cases?) This more general version is called "strong induction", and you can use the one-step induction principle to prove it. Likewise, it is possible to use the one-step induction principle to prove the two-step induction principle directly.

Comment: Yeah, but isn't OP's inductive assumption too strong?  OP assumed $A(n)$ and $A(n + 1)$ are true to prove $A(n + 2)$.  Usually, with induction, you assume $A(n)$ is true and prove $A(n + 1)$ is true.

Comment: @user46944 Either I've made a horrible mistake, or you don't know about strong induction, and I'm not sure which of the two is the case :P

Comment: I know about strong induction, but OP didn't mention that is what they were using. They stated regular induction, which makes me think that maybe they can't use strong induction.

Comment: @user46944 They are equivalent, of course: using strong induction you can prove regular induction (trivially), and using regular induction you can prove in a couple of lines that strong induction works. When anyone says "induction" to me, I understand that to include structural induction, mathematical induction, wellfounded induction (ie. strong induction), basically anything which comes to "prove that this case follows from easier cases".

Comment: My only concern was with the subtext of the OP's question -- the things they don't explicitly tell us.  It's possible they are a student and were asked to prove this using regular induction, and if they use strong induction they could be marked down.  Obviously this might not be the case, but it's worth mentioning to the OP since they are asking for verification of their proof.

Comment: Fair enough. I'll edit this answer to clarify.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply! I think things become a lot clearer now. Speaking of a proof that all $a_n$ are positive - I don't want to use this 'strong induction' again...! Is it sufficient to say that $a_1, a_2 > 0$ and therefore $a_{n+2}=a_na_{n+1}>0$ as product of positive figures; that is all $a_n>0$?

Comment: Yes, that's fine, although your argument is implicitly a strong-induction argument. You can do this at the same time as your main proof, actually, rather than a separate step: as your inductive hypothesis, assume that $a_{n+1} \geq a_{n+2} > 0$, $a_{n} \geq a_{n+1} > 0$.